# JavaScript toggle divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to toggle between 3 divs. Unfortunately it only works for 2 divs.

My code (for two divs):

```
$(function() {
  $('#playerbargreen').hide();
  $('#playerbaroff,#playerbargreen').click(function() {
    $('#playerbargreen,#playerbaroff').toggle();
  });
});
```

The end result must be:

> show first div --> click --> hide first div and show second div --> Click --> hide second div and show third div

Has someone any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: share your HTML as well

Comment: "first div --> click --> second div --> Click --> third div" - this is not toggling

Comment: @alfasin I changed the description.

Comment: Is it only supposed to work one way or does it need to be reversible by going from the 3rd Div back to the 2nd  (or 1st)?

Comment: @melkisadek No, one way is fine.

Comment: If it's only one way then you don't need to toggle anything. That switches back and forth. You just need to use `hide` and `show` from the `on click` events for each Div.

Comment: This is, still, not a description of "toggle" :) toggling has only 2 modes (like binary) on and off. Here you have 3 modes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```js
$('#Div2').hide();
$('#Div3').hide();

$('#Div1').click(function() {
    $('#Div1').hide();
    $('#Div2').show();
});

$('#Div2').click(function() {
    $('#Div2').hide();
    $('#Div3').show();
});
```

```css
div{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:green;
color:white;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Div1">div1</div>
<div id="Div2">div2</div>
<div id="Div3">div3</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Start with Div 2 & Div 3 hidden.

Create an on click event for Div 1 which hides Div 1 and shows Div 2.

Repeat for Div 2 to Div 3.

Something simple like the following should suffice:

```
$('#Div1').click(function() {
    $('#Div1').hide();
    $('#Div2').show();
});

$('#Div2').click(function() {
    $('#Div2').hide();
    $('#Div3').show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your code. I fixed my 'problem' by adding "style="display: none;" to my div.